# what does the tf.nn.lrn() method do?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is the code-snipped from the cifar10-tutorial. It's from the cifar10.py.

```
# conv1
with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 3, 64],
                                     stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
_activation_summary(conv1)

# pool1
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                     padding='SAME', name='pool1')
# norm1
norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(pool1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                name='norm1')
```

What does the tf.nn.lrn-Method do? I can't find a definition in the API Documentation on https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tf.nn.lrn` is a short for `tf.nn.local_response_normalization`.
Therefore, the documentation you may want to look at is: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/local_response_normalization

Answer (score 3):

As [nessuno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37377303/1883727) mentioned, `tf.nn.lrn` is short for `tf.nn.local_response_normalization` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#local_response_normalization))

Further, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145768/importance-of-local-response-normalization-in-cnn) provides good resources for more information into *response normalization layers*.

**From:** http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html#data-layers

> "The local response normalization layer performs a kind of “lateral inhibition” by normalizing over local input regions. In ACROSS_CHANNELS mode, the local regions extend across nearby channels, but have no spatial extent (i.e., they have shape local_size x 1 x 1). In WITHIN_CHANNEL mode, the local regions extend spatially, but are in separate channels (i.e., they have shape 1 x local_size x local_size). Each input value is divided by (1+(α/n)∑ix2i)β, where n is the size of each local region, and the sum is taken over the region centered at that value (zero padding is added where necessary)."

These layers have fallen out of favor because they had very little impact on results, and other techniques proved to be more beneficial.

Comment: which other techniques are better to use ?

Comment: maybe batchnorm?