# How to avoid Nan's in my neural network layer in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

**CODE:**

```
image_row = 640
image_col = 480
num_labels = 17
num_channels = 3 # grayscale

import numpy as np

#Load data
train_dataset, train_labels = load_file.load_data()
test_dataset = scipy.misc.imread("1501005004.548261985.png")
test_labels =  np.loadtxt("1501005004.493062654.txt", comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=False)

batch_labels = train_labels


print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)


def reformat(dataset, labels):
  dataset = dataset.reshape((-1, image_row, image_col, num_channels)).astype(np.float32)
  #labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  labels = labels.reshape((-1,num_labels)).astype(np.float32)
  return dataset, labels

train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
test_dataset, test_labels = reformat(test_dataset, test_labels)

print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)


def accuracy(labels,predictions):
    return 100.0 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(predictions - labels,2))


batch_size = 1
kernel_size = patch_size =5
depth = 16
num_hidden1 = 64
num_hidden2 = 32

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    #Input data
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=([batch_size, image_row, image_col, num_channels]))

        tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=([batch_size, num_labels]))

        tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset) 

    # Variables.
        layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.1))
        layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth]))

    # dropout
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")

    layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([patch_size, patch_size, depth, depth], stddev=0.1))
    layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[depth]))

    layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_row // 4 * image_col // 4 * depth, num_hidden1], stddev=0.1))
    layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_hidden1]))

    layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden1, num_hidden2], stddev=0.1))
    layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_hidden2]))

    layer5_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden2, num_labels], stddev=0.1))
    layer5_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]))

    def model(data):

            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, layer1_weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer1_biases)

            #   pooling

                pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],padding='SAME', name='pool1')
            norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(pool1, 4, bias=1.0,   alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,name='norm1')       

            #   layer2
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, layer2_weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer2_biases)

            #   pooling2
            pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],padding='SAME', name='pool1')
            norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(pool2, 4, bias=1.0,   alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,name='norm1')

            #   layer3
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm2, layer2_weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer2_biases)

            shape = hidden.get_shape().as_list()
            reshape = tf.reshape(hidden, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])

            #   RELU - 1e-9
            hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)    
            hidden = tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases

            # #   add a dropout
            #     hidden = tf.nn.dropout(hidden, keep_prob)

            result = tf.matmul(hidden, layer5_weights) + layer5_biases

            return result


    logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
        print ('AFTER LOGITS')
        embed()
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(logits-tf_train_labels,2))/(2*batch_size)
    #loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(logits-batch_labels,2))/(2*batch_size)

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable = False)
    start_learning_rate = 0.001
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(start_learning_rate, global_step, 100000, 0.96,staircase = True)     
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)


    #Prediction
    train_prediction = logits
    test_prediction = tf_test_dataset

num_steps  = 10000001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
        print('----------------INITIALIZED-----------------')
    for step in range(num_steps):
                print(step)
        offset = (step * batch_size)% (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        print('after offset')
        embed()
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset: (offset+batch_size), :,:,:]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset: (offset + batch_size),:]
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset: batch_data, tf_train_labels: batch_labels, keep_prob:1.0}

        _,l,prediction = session.run([optimizer, loss,train_prediction], feed_dict= feed_dict)
        print('after _,l,prediction')
        embed()
        if(step % 50 ==0):
            print("Minibatch loss %d: %f"%(step,l))
            print('Minibatch accuracy:' % accuracy(prediction, batch_labels))
```

In the above code, I am getting lots of **Inf** values in my previous hidden layer whose output is pasted below:

```
In [93]: session.run(hidden)
Out[93]: 
array([[  9.99999972e-10,   9.99999972e-10,   9.99999972e-10,
                     inf,   9.99999972e-10,   5.50044295e+28,
          9.99999972e-10,   9.99999972e-10,   3.21215463e+28,
          9.99999972e-10,   1.24344986e+28,   9.99999972e-10,
          9.99999972e-10,   2.52180816e+28,   9.99999972e-10,
          9.99999972e-10,   9.99999972e-10,   9.99999972e-10,
          1.41978562e+28,              inf,   9.99999972e-10,
```

How do I avoid these Inf values. I am a beginner in Deep Learning and Tensorflow and hence I am not sure how to go about these.

I tried adding a constant along with the relu layer: `hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases +1e-9)` , but it doesn't help.

How can I go about it?

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing the entire code. A too large learning rate may cause such a behavior, but there may be many other reasons. I would suggest to post the entire code.

Comment: Thanks @MiriamFarber ! I have updated the post with full code.

Comment: maybe try `reduce_mean` instead of `reduce_sum` while computing loss? Also, `lrn` is not advised, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376861/what-does-the-tf-nn-lrn-method-do

Comment: If you are trying to do classification, your target should be (preferably) one-hot encoded, and the loss function that I would suggest to use is cross entropy (with soft max activation on the output layer). See a tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros

Comment: Why are you initialising your weights to such big numbers? This might be one reason for NaNs

Comment: The way to avoid nans is to not write a program that generates them. Does that seem rhetorical & trivial? It's nevertheless concrete & necessary. Decide what your output is as a function of your input, and know the specs of operators you call, and call them in such a way that they calculate your output. Is that just the definition of "programming"? Yet people think they are programming when they are not. At what point in your calls is the result not what you expect? Please read & act on  [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In general, this problem shows up with exploding gradients, you need to clip the gradients.

```
# Replace this lines with the following
>optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
grads_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
grads_vars = clip_grad_norms(grads_vars, max_norm=10)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_vars)

# finally
> _,l,prediction = session.run([optimizer, loss,train_prediction], feed_dict= feed_dict)
#replace with
_,l,prediction = session.run([train_op, loss,train_prediction],  feed_dict= feed_dict)

# clip_grad_norms function link
https://github.com/n3011/tefla/blob/master/tefla/core/base.py#L253
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code above, it looks like you haven't got any activation function between layer 4 and 5.

```
 hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)    
 hidden = tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases
 result = tf.matmul(hidden, layer5_weights) + layer5_biases

 return result
```

Depending on your initialization of weights and biases it can be a reason for over/under flowing weights.